# Вопрос по туле Jmeter, подскажите пожалуйста, что означает "Runs in 10 threads once."

Tags: jmeter, qaction

Что имеется в ввиду, запуск 10ти потоков за один раз? я не совсем понимаю этот момент.
[image: Скрин]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А почему вы спрашиваете об этом здесь, а не автора этого документа? Английский там очень кривой, но по контексту я могу предположить что в первой [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) речь идет о 10 пользователях и 1 итерации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а во второй - об одном пользователе и неограниченном количестве итераций

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

к пункту 2 тоже есть некоторые вопросы т.к. [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) не выполняет никаких запросов, это просто конфигурационный элемент где можно указать значения "по умолчанию" для разных полюшек [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) сэмплера, так что у автора этого документа беда не только с английским, он еще и не совсем профпригоден.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за подсказку, я примерно так и догадывался. Согласен, что англ. кривой, поэтому и не совсем понятно, о чём идёт речь.